# How to make the react-native android app ask the user for a grant of the push notifications at the install or run time?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, android-permissions

The problem is to make the react-native android app ask the user for a grant of the push notification.
This is a related issue, and I need a solution.
[github issue](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1325)

Comment: Are you using expo?

Comment: no, i don't use expo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **expo** you can try the following:

```js
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

const {status} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
    alert('No notification permissions!');
}

let expoPushToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
```